# Handle Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The request timed out?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I am using web references in my app but I am getting following exception.

I have used bellow code.

`obj` is my web reference object. It does not take `obj` directly that is why I have used variable for that. But still it's not working, it takes me automatically to previous activity.

```
var url=obj.ToString();
            // Create a new WebRequest Object to the mentioned URL.
            WebRequest myWebRequest=WebRequest.Create(url);
            Console.WriteLine("\nThe Timeout time of the request before setting is : {0} milliseconds",myWebRequest.Timeout);

            // Set the 'Timeout' property in Milliseconds.
            myWebRequest.Timeout=10000;

            // This request will throw a WebException if it reaches the timeout limit before it is able to fetch the resource.
            WebResponse myWebResponse=myWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

> Unhandled Exception: System.Net.WebException: The request timed out
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebClientProtocol.GetWebResponse
>   (System.Net.WebRequest request) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: What is the value of "url"?

Comment: For your WriteLine you have to set myWebRequest.Timeout before your output, otherwise you get the default value (what's maybe not 10sec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It hit your timeout, meaning it did not get a response from the URL it called in time.

Check the URL in a browser.  Check if it returns anything and how long it takes.

Make sure you don't need to configure a proxy.

Comment: Ok... so whay happens when you put it in a browser?

Comment: It is showing all methods properly and it doesnt timed out.what shoul I use instade of url in WebRequest.Create(url);

Comment: A url is fine, that is what it is designed to take.  You have some other issue, one possibility is you need to set a Proxy on the request.

Comment: how to set a Proxy on the request?

Comment: First check if you need to, by looking in your internet explorer connection settings to see if your browser is using one.  If it is, you will need to use these details to create a WebProxy object that you can then set on the WebRequest's Proxy property.